# Design of a peculiar Wheel of Fortune

Tags: probability, combinatorics, geometry, combinatorial-geometry, gambling

Consider the two wheels of fortune illustrated below.

[image]

The first one (left) is constituted by $c$ sectors with the same arc length: $\alpha$ of which are red, $\beta$ of which are blue and $\gamma$ of which are green.

The second one (right) is constituted by three sectors with the same arc length: One is red, one is blue and one is green.

On the first wheel, we perform $2$ turns, and we evaluate the ratio $r$ between the probability "to get at least one red sector and at least one blue sector" and the probability "to get both times a green sector", assuming that the order of the turns **matters**.

It is easy to show that this ratio is

> $$r=\left[\left(\frac{\alpha}{c}\right)\left(\frac{\beta}{c}\right)+\left(\frac{\beta}{c}\right)\left(\frac{\alpha}{c}\right)\right]/\left[\left(\frac{\gamma}{c}\right)\left(\frac{\gamma}{c}\right)\right]=
> $$
>   $$
> =\frac{2\alpha\beta}{c^2}/\left(\frac{\gamma}{c}\right)^2=\frac{2\alpha\beta}{\gamma^2}.$$

On the second wheel we perform $n$ turns, and we evaluate the ratio $s$ between the probability "to get at least one red sector and at least one blue sector" and the probability "to get all the $n$ times the green sector", in case the order of the turns **does not matter**.

It is trivial to show that there are $\binom{k+n-1}{n}=\binom{n+2}{n}$ ways in which we can distribute $n$ indistinguishable turns among $k=3$ distinguishable sectors, in case the order of the turn does not matter. It is also easy to see that, among these $\binom{n+2}{n}$ combinations, only one contains all the $n$ turns in one sector, whereas there are $\binom{n}{2}$ combinations which contain at least one turn in one sector and at least one turn in another one (again, these quantities are evaluated assuming that the order of the $n$ turns is irrelevant).

Therefore, the ratio we are looking for is

> $$
> s=\left[\frac{\binom{n}{2}}{\binom{n+2}{n}}\right]/\left[\frac{1}{\binom{n+2}{n}}\right]=\binom{n}{2}.
> $$

My question is

> **How can we build the first wheel, in  case the design requires that $r\cdot s=\frac{2\alpha\beta}{\gamma^2}\cdot\binom{n}{2}<1$, and that $n>2$ ?**

Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: I have a problem with your second computation : if you take order into account (we are talking probabilities, right ?), then I find $s=3^n-2^{n+1}+1$, which is clearly different from your answer.

Comment: First a note that in your final block you write $c^2$ instead of $\gamma^2$. I don't quite see the problem yet. You want to have a design that fixes the problem. But do you want this for general $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ and $n$? If you fix $\alpha,\beta=1$ we can find an expression for $\gamma$ in terms of $n$ that satisfies it for all $n >2$. Or are you looking for a fixed combination of $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ such that this holds for all $n>2$ such that $\gamma$ does not depend on $n$?

Comment: @Jan Thanks for pointing out the mistake! I would like to know if we can find a $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ (integers!) such that $r\cdot s<1$, in case $n>2$.

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS Yes, your calculation is related to the case in which the order matters, but this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: How does the order of turns matter in the first case? Each of the two events you describe seems to be invariant under interchanging the two spins.

Comment: @HenningMakholm This is my greatest problem, thanks for pointing it out. So, if you consider $\gamma^k/ c^k$, this is the ratio between all the possible ways in which we can choose $\gamma$ indexed elements, in $k$ trials, in case the order matters, divided by the number of ways in which we can distinguish $c$ index elements in $k$ trials, when the order matters. Am I right?

Comment: When you throw two indistinguishable dices, you have to paint them to get the correct sample space. Right ? So there are $6^2=36$ individual outcomes, not $\binom{2}{7}=21$.

Comment: imagine the possible outcomes as sequences such as AAABGGABA, which are distinguishable only for the amout of As Bs and Gs, since the order does not matter... there are $\binom{n+2}{2}$ possible combinations. Only one, out of $\binom{n+2}{2}$, is GGGGGGG...

Comment: What @NicolasFRANCOIS is trying to say is that while the amount of distinct events may be smaller, the probability of them is not the same. Back to the dice example: If you throw 2 dice there are 11 different possible outcome. However the probability of throwing a sum of 2 is 1/36 while the probability of throwing a 7 is 1/6.

Comment: Exactly my thoughts :-)

Comment: I see, but in that case, to calculate all the possible outcomes, the order matters. For the second wheel, I have to evaluate the case in which the order does _not_ matter, hence the binomial.

Comment: I put a picture to explain what I mean!

Comment: It doesn't let me upload this image. Can you see it here https://photos.app.goo.gl/UAd5a4SEHduNJosn8 ?

Comment: @HenningMakholm in case you can access to the picture in the  link above, you can see for each $n=2,3,4$ the $\binom{n+2}{n}=6,10,15$ possible cases (rows) of ending with a certain sequence (the downward arrows represent the stop of the wheel). On the left of each table, I put the $\binom{n}{2}=1,3,6$ cases related to "get at least one red sector and at least one blue sector" (half-red-half-blue dot), whereas on the right of each table I put the only case (green dot) related to "get always the green sector". The order does not matter!

Comment: @AndreaPrunotto: Counting the outcomes in that picture is not particularly useful if you want to end up with a probability, because those outcomes are not equally likely!

Comment: @HenningMakholm But, speaking about the second wheel, since each of the three sectors has the same arc length, aren't all the $\binom{n+2}{n}$ sequences all equiprobable?

Comment: @AndreaPrunotto: No. For example, for $n=2$, the outcome "1 red, 1 green, 0 blue" is twice as likely as the outcome "2 red, 0 green, 0 blue". Because the concrete sequences `RG` and `GR` and `RR` _are_ equally likely (each has a probability of $\frac19$), and the two first of them both become "1 red, 1 green, 0 blue".

Comment: Each sequence is equiprobable. But not each kind of sequence, as my picture shows. That's why the probability to get at least one red and at least one blue is $\frac{\binom{n}{2}}{\binom{n+2}{n}}$. Or, what I am missing?

Comment: You talk as if you could change probabilities by declaring things to be distinguishable or not. If you build that wheel and turn it, you'll find that it produces certain results with certain probabilities. Those probabilities are the ones we calculate by treating all results as equiprobable, distinguishing results according to the order of the turns. You can certainly **count** things while not distinguishing according to the order the turns; but it makes no sense to call the ratios of the resulting counts "probabilities". They're not -- at least not probabilities for the wheel you describe.

Comment: @joriki Well, I call probability what sticks to the definition of probability. The number $x$ of sequences of turns containing a specific amount of red, green and blue sectors, divided by all the possible sequences of turns containing any possible amount of red, green and blue sectors is  $x/\binom{n+2}{n}$, where $x$ is the number of "favorable" sequences for that specific amount of sectors of the three different colors. This definition satisfies the axioms of probability, the theorem of total probability, and Bayes' theorem. As an interesting exercise, you can verify it easily.

Comment: @joriki However, I see your point about the distinguishable items. in the second wheel, the sector are clearly distinguishable, but the (independent) turns are not. This, I agree, is questionable. However, the order of the trials is neglected both at the numerator and denominator of the definition.

Comment: No. The probability to get the green sector $n$ times if you turn this wheel $n$ times is $3^{-n}\ne\binom{n+2}n^{-1}$. Not distinguishing between the turns doesn't just scale the numerator and the denominator; it leads to different ratios. Of course you're right that these ratios also satisfy the probability axioms; and you may even be able to construct some physical system in which they occur as probabilities. I'm just saying that the wheel you describe is not that physical system, and talking about these ratios as probabilities in the context of this wheel is meaningless and misleading.

Comment: @joriki I see your point, that is in agreement with the comments of other users. Thanks for pointing this out. I will think better about it, especially about the physical system satisfying this peculiar definition of probability. Any suggestion, maybe? Thanks again!

Comment: You could have $n+2$ holes, uniformly randomly select two of them to put balls in, and then flood the holes from the left with e.g. red liquid and flood the holes from the right with e.g. blue liquid. The setup would be such that the holes are connected and the liquid fills the holes up to the point where it's blocked by a ball in a hole. In the holes that don't contain liquid, you'd be able to see the green bottom. Then the probabilities for the numbers of red, green and blue holes observed would be the ratios you want.

Comment: @joriki I didn't really understand your system, but thanks! Maybe I will post another question asking for further suggestions of such system - just not to make this comments thread too long. Thanks again joriki!

Comment: @joriki https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2875383/559615 !

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done without the trivial solutions such as setting $\alpha,\beta=0$. This would lead to $s=0$ and $r=0$ so $s\cdot r <1$ trivially.

Since this is probably not what you are looking for note that when $\alpha,\beta$ and $\gamma$ fixed with $\alpha \cdot \beta>0$.
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{2\alpha\beta}{\gamma^2}\cdot\binom{n}{2}=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{2\alpha\beta}{\gamma^2}\cdot\frac{n!}{2(n-2)!}=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{2\alpha\beta}{\gamma^2}\cdot n \cdot (n-1)=\infty$$

If you were to make $\alpha,\beta$ or $\gamma$ a function of $n$ this could work.

Comment: Well, he didn't ask for the ratio to be lower than $1$ for ALL $n$, did he ? So maybe you can take $c=n$, in which case all you have to do is take $\alpha>1$ or $\beta>1$...

Comment: If you are asking it as a function of $n$ you can simply set $\alpha,\beta$ to 1 and easily find $\gamma$ as a function of $n$ that would satisfy that constraint.